# Itanium Development Dabbling Kit

Tags: hardware

A few years back you could buy a development kit that had a next generation processor, perhaps some memory, and a little IO. Further back was the world of transputers that came on a board in various array sizes. For huge amounts of money now days you can buy FPGA kits. I think the acronym is. And of course most imbedded control chips and boards come with either an emulator or mockup boards for programming and debugging.

I want to play with an Itanium. I am interested in the assembly features. Don’t need it to have masses of memory or be super fast. What is the simplest way to do this. I probably don’t have the budget for a modern standalone system using one as it core processor. I am rather looking for a dev kit with one on a PCI board or development kit programmed serially or something like that.

Any ideas or experience in this area gentlemen.

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Then how do we move it.

Comment: I can't keep up with all the changes. Going to have to write a small Neural Net in the future to auto route questions to the correct expert site <:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itaniums have been out for a while. Chances are the early generations are already being retired, and you could pick up a used server cheap. It won't be a kit, but it should be fully functional.

Comment: I shall look around for one.